# Why do we not know which tribe we are from

Tags: shevatim-12-tribes

Some people are from the tribe of Levi. But no one today knows which tribe they are from. Why is this? Even if you say the 10 exiled tribes were lost. They still had people from each tribe in Israel.

Comment: People forget stuff, especially if they aren't written down. There used to be in Yerushalayim a genealogical archive for the most important Jewish families. It was burned down during the Great Revolt. And the rest of the Jews? I guess when you don't write everything down, you eventually forget.

Comment: @Harel13 This is exactly why Rebbi sought to write down the Mishnah

Comment: There are families with traditions of their tribe.

Comment: For kohanim/leviim, it makes a difference which tribe they are part of, even today, so that tradition would get passed down throughout generations. For other tribes, it doesn't really matter, so most people eventually lost the tradition.